# Como trocar a cor do botão que for pressionado?

Tags: android

Estou desenvolvendo um app que gera aleatoriamente uma conta de adição e gera 4 valores como possíveis respostas e que são colocados em 4 botões (também de uma forma aleatória).

Eu gostaria de saber como eu faço para, quando eu clicar em qualquer um dos botões (a possível resposta), só ele trocar de cor e não deixar selecionar os outros (não deixar que os outros troquem de cor).

Obs.: Este processo de escolha seria repetido mais 9 vezes.

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_realizar_contas);
        final TextView num1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.num1);
        final TextView num2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.num2);
        final Button op1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.op1);
        final Button op2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.op2);
        final Button op3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.op3);
        final Button op4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.op4);
        final Button avancar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_avancar);

        esc = numeroDecisao();
        res1 = numeroAleatorio();
        res2 = numeroAleatorio();

        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Esc " + esc, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        if (esc == 1) {
            val1 = res1 + res2;
            val2 = (numeroAleatorio() + numeroAleatorio()) + 1;
            val3 = (numeroAleatorio() + numeroAleatorio()) + 2;
            val4 = (numeroAleatorio() + numeroAleatorio()) + 3;

        } else if (esc == 2) {
            val1 = (numeroAleatorio() + numeroAleatorio()) + 3;
            val2 = res1 + res2;
            val3 = (numeroAleatorio() + numeroAleatorio()) + 7;
            val4 = (numeroAleatorio() + numeroAleatorio()) + 1;

        } else if (esc == 3) {
            val1 = (numeroAleatorio() + numeroAleatorio()) + 8;
            val2 = (numeroAleatorio() + numeroAleatorio()) + 9;
            val3 = res1 + res2;
            val4 = (numeroAleatorio() + numeroAleatorio()) + 10;
        } else if (esc == 4) {
            val1 = (numeroAleatorio() + numeroAleatorio()) + 7;
            val2 = (numeroAleatorio() + numeroAleatorio()) + 6;
            val3 = (numeroAleatorio() + numeroAleatorio()) + 5;
            val4 = res1 + res2;
        }

        num1.setText(Integer.toString(res1));
        num2.setText(Integer.toString(res2));
        op1.setText(Integer.toString(val1));
        op2.setText(Integer.toString(val2));
        op3.setText(Integer.toString(val3));
        op4.setText(Integer.toString(val4));

        op1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                op1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.botao_customizado);
                press = press + 1;
            }
        });


        //BOTÃO - AVANÇAR - Realizar a procdimento anterior 9 vezes
        avancar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int cont = 0;
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Acertos " + acertos, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                while (cont != 9) {
                    res1 = numeroAleatorio();
                    res2 = numeroAleatorio();
                    esc = numeroDecisao();

                    if (esc == 1) {
                        val1 = res1 + res2;
                        val2 = (numeroAleatorio() + numeroAleatorio()) + 9;
                        val3 = (numeroAleatorio() + numeroAleatorio()) + 3;
                        val4 = (numeroAleatorio() + numeroAleatorio()) + 1;

                    } else if (esc == 2) {
                        val1 = (numeroAleatorio() + numeroAleatorio()) + 4;
                        val2 = res1 + res2;
                        val3 = (numeroAleatorio() + numeroAleatorio()) + 5;
                        val4 = (numeroAleatorio() + numeroAleatorio()) + 7;

                    } else if (esc == 3) {
                        val1 = (numeroAleatorio() + numeroAleatorio()) + 8;
                        val2 = (numeroAleatorio() + numeroAleatorio()) + 9;
                        val3 = res1 + res2;
                        val4 = (numeroAleatorio() + numeroAleatorio()) + 10;
                    } else if (esc == 4) {
                        val1 = (numeroAleatorio() + numeroAleatorio()) + 10;
                        val2 = (numeroAleatorio() + numeroAleatorio()) + 3;
                        val3 = (numeroAleatorio() + numeroAleatorio()) + 1;
                        val4 = res1 + res2;
                    }

                    num1.setText(Integer.toString(res1));
                    num2.setText(Integer.toString(res2));
                    op1.setText(Integer.toString(val1));
                    op2.setText(Integer.toString(val2));
                    op3.setText(Integer.toString(val3));
                    op4.setText(Integer.toString(val4));
                    cont++;


                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: O que você já tem? Onde exatamente está tendo problemas? É com a troca de cor? É com o desativamento dos outros botões? É com o algoritmo? Quebre seu problema em etapas e tente resolver uma coisa de cada vez. Do jeito que está, a pergunta está muito ampla.

Comment: Valeu pela dica, bom vamos pelo o primeiro problema, eu tenho uma aplicação que vai repetir 10 vezes questões de adição e que cada vez vai gerar 4 respostas, eu consigo fazer a troca da cor do botão na primeira vez ao clicar na "reposta", mas já na segunda vez em diante, o botão fica com a cor do que eu cliquei anteriormente. Como faço para arrumar isso?

Comment: Pode colar aqui o trecho do código onde altera a cor do botão para analisarmos?

Comment: Coloquei, valeu!

Answer (score 1):

Você pode tentar utilizar a função **setBackgroundColor** e inserir um valor hexadecimal da cor.

`opt1.setBackgroundColor(0xFFFFA500);`

Se já conhece CSS, você pode alterar a cor trocando os últimos 6 valores (FFA500) pela cor de escolha. Existem diversas tabelas de cores hexadecimal na internet.

para mais informações veja um post em inglês sobre o assunto.
[Android Button color changing on onClick?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17189715/android-button-color-changing-on-onclick)

Comment: Valeu, já consegui aqui, pensei em uma maneira melhor, sem precisar altera a cor do botão. Valeu mesmo!!!